# Cant bale to mock a function mockito android

Tags: android, unit-testing, mockito

The below is my class contains the map creation.

```
 public class ManagerImpl extends Manager {
    HashMap<String, String> creatMap(String hint) throws IOException {

       HashMap<String, String> genericKeysMap = new HashMap<String, String>();
       genericKeysMap.put(Schema.encryptionKey, encodeBase64(enKey));
       return map;
     }

   String encodeBase64(byte[] value) {
     return Base64.encodeToString(value, Base64.DEFAULT);
   }
 }
```

And i want to unit test the createMap(). So i want to mock the encodeBase64() function.

Below is my unit test.

```
@Mock
private String testEncodedString = "encodedString";

@Test
public void createVMapTest() {
    MangerImpl manger = Mockito.spy(MangerImpl.class);
    doReturn(testEncodedString).when(manger).encodeBase64("byte".getBytes());
    try {
       HashMap<String, String> map = manger.creatMap(hint);
       assertNotNull(vmap);
       assertTrue(map.size() == 1);
     } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
     }
 }
```

I have mocked the encodeBase64 function. But the method is getting called and returning the original object not the mocked one and i am getting the below error.

```
  Error: 
 java.lang.RuntimeException: Method encodeToString in android.util.Base64 not mocked. See http://g.co/androidstudio/not-mocked for details.

at android.util.Base64.encodeToString(Base64.java)
```

I don't know hat i am missing. Could anyone please help me out on this?

Answer (score 0):

The issue is here

```
@Test
public void createVMapTest() {
    // MangerImpl manger = Mockito.spy(MangerImpl.class);
    // Above line should be replaced with 
    MangerImpl manger = Mockito.spy(new ManagerImpl());
}
```

Because spy() is supposed to be used on objects where you want to mock some method but call another real method. In your case you want to mock `ManagerImpl#encodeBase64` and call real method `ManagerImpl#creatMap`